# LESS - Mixin as variable argument

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I'm importing bootstrap files and rewriting the source variables, eg :

```
@import "./../../../../vendor/bootstrap/less/scaffolding.less";
@import "./../../../../vendor/bootstrap/less/type.less";
@import "./../../../../vendor/bootstrap/less/code.less";
@import "./../../../../vendor/bootstrap/less/grid.less";
@import "./../../../../vendor/bootstrap/less/tables.less";
@import "./../../../../vendor/bootstrap/less/forms.less";
@import "./../../../../vendor/bootstrap/less/buttons.less";
//etc ...

@font-size-base: 100%;
```

Then in my own variables.less I set something like that, a mixin for rem font sizing

```
.font-size(@sizeValue) {
  @remValue: @sizeValue;
  @pxValue: (@sizeValue * 10);
  font-size: ~"@{pxValue}px";
  font-size: ~"@{remValue}rem";
}
```

Now of course, I dont see how I can make that working, this is what I wanted, and it doesn't work (input not recognised) :

```
// In bootstrap import file, trying to overwrite their variable parameter with my mixin
@font-size-h2: .font-size(32);
```

Any way to do what I want ?

Comment: is `.font-size` is a class or what ?

Comment: Mixins are not functions, they do not return a value. Thus you can't assign the content, a mixin call expends to, to a variable (for your snippet the result would look like [this](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/7375cbfc64927b6798f0), i.e. it does not make any sense). I'd suggest you to re-read Less documentation for mixin and variable  basics.

Comment: As for "Any way to do what I want?", look how the `@font-size-h2` variable [is used](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v3.3.5/less/type.less#L48), i.e you will not be able to use it to set both px and rem values. Thus instead of overriding the variable you'll need to simply override the properties of the corresponding rulesets with whatever you need values.

Comment: what you mean is that I won't be able to override bootstrap variable. I'd rather drop IE8 support to be honest

Comment: "won't be able to override bootstrap variable" - that's not what I wrote, please re-read.

Comment: no no, I mean I won't be able to achieve my goal by overriding the @font-size-h2 variable. I will have to write `h2 {.font-size(2.2);}`

Comment: `h2 {.font-size(2.2)}` - yep.